# Least-Worst name data matching method between 1) a list of full names, and 2) a list of last names and first initials

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matching

For reasons outside my of control, I am sadly responsible for attempting to match two generally incompatible datasets. I was hoping for some advice and refinement on my current strategy, or a proposal for something entirely different.

**Problem**

I have two sets of data that contains different information about the same people, and my task is as efficiently as possible match up these two sets of data so all the information about a person can be stored in the same place. We're talking about a list of approx. ~3,000 people on each list. Names on one list, because of terrible data management, won't necessarily be on the other, so there's no guarantee of a match. The only common piece of data between both sets are names. Data set (1) contains people's full names in one cell. Data set (2) contains people's first initial and last name, separated by a comma. Here's some (fake) examples, with me having matched the data.

| Data Set (1) | Data Set (2) |
| --- | --- |
| Alexander Brodbois | Brodbois, A |
| Anna Brulé | Brule, A |
| Auben Caramell | Caramell, A |

This is currently being done on excel, but I also often use google sheets.

**Current Strategy and its problems**
My current strategy is to generate a common search key that has this format:

> [LastName][FirstInitial]

So, for example:

| Data Set (1) | Data Set (2) | Search Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Auben Caramell | Caramell, A | CaramellA |

This is working with ~90% accuracy; however I've noticed that there's a %5-7 failure due to a few cases:

- One data set has an accent on a name, and the other doesn't; e.g. BruléA does not match with BruleA
- Sometimes people have multiple names (up to 5), and the final name on Data Set (1) does not always correspond to what counts as the 'last name' in Data Set (2); it could be the 3rd or 4th name.
- One data set has someone's name as one combined word, whereas the other counts the last name as being a 'middle' and a 'last' name.

I am also concerned with the possibility of incorrect matches, although this seems to have not happened yet. When I looked at one of the data sets, there was only 2 people with the same last name, and they had different initials.

I'm not expected to get 100% accuracy, but higher the better, obviously.

Any advice? The method I currently have works, but is not reliable and will require me to do heaps of manual work. I would just do the manual work, but this is a task that will have to be done monthly, and I don't have control over how the input is presented to me.

I swear there must be a smart regex method here that I haven't thought of, but I'm no expert at this.

Comment: Side note, Excel is not synonymous with Google Sheets. Which of the two are you actually using?

Comment: Excel. But I'd take a google sheets solution.

Comment: You can do some of this in Power Query (available in Excel since 2010). You could Remove the accents, create two new columns with Last Name and First Initial; do the same in the other data set, and then Join them with those columns being the key. The last name in DataSet_2 might be picked by being the last "word" before the comma. If there is no separator between last name and other names, you'll probably need to check that manually. Depending on what your data really looks like, there might be other methods.

Comment: This is a very complicated problem to solve for computers, and falls outside the “complexity horizon” of Excel.  But this *may* help.  Microsoft offers a “fuzzy logic” plugin that you can try, and see if it gets you close:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try these two suggestions. I agree with you @MaxR, a certain amount of manual work is just inevitable given the problem. But this looks like a good plugin, thanks.